# How to stream data from request.get and push to array [nodejs]

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do continuous stream from request.get and then push data to the array. In the following code data is getting pushed to an array but the when I print the array it has more elements then it should have.

```
var arrItem=[]    
for (a=0; a< array.length; a++){   
        var uri = "http://localhost:8080/getItem"
          await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var respt= request.get(
              uri , function (error, response, body) {
              }).on('data', function(data,error) {          
              if(error){
                reject(error);
              } else {
                arrItem.push(data)
                resolve(data)
                // console.log('decoded chunk: ' + data)
              }
            }).pipe()

          });
          console.log(arrItem.length)
        }
```

How can I stream the output to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `async-await` with `BPromise.all` to achieve the result:

```
const BPromise = require('bluebird');
async function getItem() {
  const arrItem = await BPromise.all(
    array.map( (item) =>  
      request.get(
        uri , function (error, response, body) {
        }).on('data', function(data,error) { return data}).pipe()
    ));
    return arrItem;
};
console.log(getItem());
```

> Install `bluebird` node module.

Comment: This gives an error stating (node:67130) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined